# facebook connect php api, how show friends already using an app

Tags: php, facebook, api, show

what code could i use to display all users who are using my app? i am getting the facebook session as such:

```
            require_once basepath.'/includes/facebook/src/facebook.php';
            // Create our Application instance.
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
              'appId' => '#####',
              'secret' => '####',
              'cookie' => true,
            ));

            $session = $facebook->getSession();
```

how do i show connected users? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a FQL Query like `select uid, name, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and is_app_user=1` to get your friends already using an app.

Answer (score 2):

i think this is what you're looking for https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/

Answer (score 1):

this page may help: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getAppUsers/

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use [facepile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile/) you need to add data-app-id and don't add data-href because if you will add data-href then system will check that url not your app so the facepile div will look like this:

```
<div class="fb-facepile" data-app-id="YOUR_APP_ID" data-max-rows="1" data-colorscheme="light" data-size="small" data-show-count="true"></div>
```